# Stream de vídeo com Nodejs e Socket.io

Tags: node.js, vídeo, socket.io, stream, html5-video

Preciso de ajuda para fazer stream com Nodejs e Socket.io. Estou usando a biblioteca rtsp-ffmpeg para realizar o stream. Consegui executá-la transmitindo em formato img conforme a própria documentação especifica, mas não estou conseguindo enviar um mp4 mesmo após ter setado o parâmetro correto na biblioteca (https://github.com/agsh/rtsp-ffmpeg)

```
const app = require('express')()
, server = require('http').Server(app)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
, rtsp = require('./lib/rtsp-ffmpeg');

// usar rtsp = require('rtsp-ffmpeg') se caso tiver instalado o pacote

server.listen(6147, function(){
 console.log('Servidor executando em localhost:6147');
});

var uri = 'rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4'
    , stream = new rtsp.FFMpeg({input: uri, resolution: '320x240', quality: 3});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 var pipeStream = function(data) {
    console.log('Client has connected to the server!')
    socket.emit('data', data.toString('base64'));
};
stream.on('data', pipeStream);
 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    stream.removeListener('data', pipeStream);
   });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Este é o HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" controls autoplay autobuffer>
        <source id="conteudo">
    </video>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById('conteudo'),
            socket = io('');
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            video.src = 'data:video/mp4;base64,' + data;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "VideoStream",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A real-time media player",
  "repository": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4",
    "socket.io": "^1.4", 
    "jade" : "0.28.x"
  },
  "author": "Marco Gorak"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente essas opções :

```
var videoOptions = {
  fps: 12,
  transition: false,
  loop: 1, // segundos 
  videoBitrate: 2048,
  videoCodec: 'libx264',
  size: '1920x1080',
  outputOptions: ['-pix_fmt yuv420p'],
  format: 'mp4'
}
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado